# How to handle overlapping Fragments in TabLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, fragment

I have a TabLayout with two fragments which  both of them shows a RecyclerView (one movies and the other tv shows). The TabLayout works perfectly but the problem comes when I click on the image of a film. The click in a movie should make a transaction to the movie details fragment. But when this happens the ListFragment with the TabLayout appears under the new one so the two of them are displayed.

My ActivityMain code where I call the transaction and where I set the Page Adapter:

```
override fun onMovieClicked(iDMovie: Int) {

        val movieDetails = MovieDetailsFragment.newInstance(iDMovie)
        supportFragmentManager.
           beginTransaction().
           replace(R.id.main_container, movieDetails).
           addToBackStack(null).
           commit()
    }

private fun setStatePageAdapter() {

        val fragmentAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = fragmentAdapter

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    }
```

My PageAdapterClass:

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager): FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

   override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                ListFilmFragment()
            }
            else -> {
                return TVShowsFragmentList()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "Películas"
            else -> {
                return "Series"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Layouts:
Activity Main:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabBackground="@color/black"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Observation: With FrameLayout instead of Coordinator didn't work either.

The result I get is the following:
The FragmentDetails overlaps the filmListFragment and the two of them are displayed at the same time. But only the details fragments has to be displayed.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s deal only with `Fragment`s' `View`s. They will not remove, replace, or otherwise hide any `View`s that do not belong to a `Fragment`. Your `onMovieClicked()` method is just sticking a `MovieDetailsFragment` on top of everything in the `main_container` `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem in **2 ways**

**first:**
You can **hide** your ViewPager and TabLayout befor inflating Your fragments.
so change your MovieClicked method like below

```
override fun onMovieClicked(iDMovie: Int) {

   viewPager.visibiliy=View.Gone;
   tabLayout.visibility=View.Gone
    val movieDetails = MovieDetailsFragment.newInstance(iDMovie)
    supportFragmentManager.
       beginTransaction().
       replace(R.id.main_container, movieDetails).
       addToBackStack(null).
       commit()
}
```

**Seconde:**
You can change your fragments XML **Root elements**
 1-set a background for each of you fragments `android:background="yourColor"` to hide
 behind layout .
 2-set OnClick attribute to true to make app receive your current layout 
 onClickListeners not behind layout  with `android:onClick=true`

Your Xml must be like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"<!--White Color for example-->
>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you have **several fragment layout** that has your problem
You can set an style and change your fragment style to your style
So declare an style in `style.xml`

```
<style name="fragmentsRootElementStyle">
    <item name="android:onClick">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and set **style** for fragment layouts root as below

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/fragmentsRootElementsStyle"
    >

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but now if I press the back button the viewpager is not displayed cause it's visibility is gone so how can i manage this situation?.

Comment: Use this condition in Your Activity onBackPressed method ```if(getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_container)!=null)``` and then show your tablayout and viewpager  this check weather your fragments have shown or not

Comment: Also you can use second way